# IIS Redirect one URL with query string to another with a new query string

Tags: iis, redirect

I am scratching my head looking for a way to redirect one url with a specific query string to another with a new specific query string in IIS.

example -

http://example.com/10/list_display.asp?a=b -->
http://example.com/display.asp?c=d

Any clues on how to do this - we know in advance what the old and new query strings should be so want to avoid regular expressions.

Thanks,
Sean

Comment: Any specific reason for doing on IIS, it can be done easily in code?

Comment: I would say handling redirects from legacy site urls to new urls is best handled by the server - not by adding a bunch of conditional code that would need to be re-deployed and tested any time a change was made.

Answer (score 0):

The add

```
<rule name="Rewrite rule1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="10/list_display.asp" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="profession=2599" />
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="country=The*" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="the-redirect.aspx" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
```